Sum of product of possible strings
Problem:

Let $S_n$ be the set of all strings of length $n$ whose only characters are $1$ and $*$. For any element $x$ in $S_n$ for some $n$, let $f(x)$ be the result obtained after evaluating the string $x$ as an expression by removing all unused or repeated $*$ terms. For example, the string $``*1 **11 **111***"$ would be evaluated as $1 \cdot 11 \cdot 111 = 1221$, ignoring the repeated, beginning, and end multiplication characters. Let $a_n = \displaystyle\sum_{x \in S_n} f(x)$, as in the sum of $f(x)$ across all $x \in S_n$. Then find $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{11^n}$$(Note that a string $x$ with only $*$ characters is defined to have $f(x) = 1$).

My thoughts:
I tried to set up a recursive relation between $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$. But they do not seem to have an easy connection between them.
For instance:
$11*11 = 121$
$11*111 = 1221$
$111*111 = 12321$
$111*1111 = 123321$
Sometimes there is an extra two, sometimes an extra three, and the digits shift, so it seems hard to deal with.
Then I tried a generating function of the form $g(x) = \frac{(10^1 - 1)}{9}\frac{(10^2 - 1)}{9}\dots\frac{(10^x - 1)}{9}$ but this did not lead anywhere. How should I approach this problem?

Where did you get the problem from? Is there any reason to believe that it there will be a "nice" answer?

I got it from a friend on aops, and the original problem stated that the final sum will be a rational number. So hopefully there is a nice solution!

Did you mean for the generating function to just be $g(x)=0$?

My bad, I messed up the indices. Edited!

Hint: Let $k_n$ be the sum of string of length $n$ that end with $k$ 1's (including $k = 0 $. Find a recurrence relation for the $k_n$, and substitute that in.

Sorry, but could you explicitly give the recursion? I'll try to work backwards and prove it

The crux is that $K_n = a_{n-K-1} \times \underbrace{11 \ldots 11}_{k \text{ times}}$ and $a_n = \sum K_n$. Substitute that into $ S = \sum a_n/11^n$  and change the order of summation to get an equation in terms of $S$.

Nice numeration technique.

Let $ K_n$ be the sum arising from strings of length $n$ that end with $K$ 1's.
As always, let the empty product be 1, meaning $a_0 = 1$.
Show that

$0_{n} = a_{n-1} $
$n_n =  \underbrace{11 \ldots 11}_{n \text{ times}} = \frac{ 10^{n} - 1 } { 9}$
For $0 < K < n$, $K_n = a_{n-K-1} \times \underbrace{11 \ldots 11}_{K \text{ times}} = a_{n-K-1} \times \frac{ 10^{K} -1 } { 9}$.

Show this by appending $* \underbrace{11 \ldots 11}_{K \text{ times}}$ to any string of length $n-K-1$.
This works for $ K = n$ if we define $a_{-1} = 1$. (You can think of it as the empty product of "We do not need a $*$". Alternatively, deal with it separately.)
This doesn't work for $K = 0$, we have to deal with it separately.


$ a_n = \sum_{K=0}^n K_n$ by definition.

Using the above formula, $a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} \times \frac{10^1-1}{9} +   a_{n-3} \times \frac{10^2-1}{9}  + \ldots + a_{-1} \times \frac{10^n-1}{9} $
This is the recurrence that we use. In this form, it becomes a standard problem.


$ \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^\infty   \frac { 10^i - 1 } { 9 \times 11^i } = \frac{11}{10}  $.

Evaluate it as the difference of 2 geometric progressions.


Now we're ready to consider $\displaystyle S = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{ a_n}{ 11^n}$.
Remember that for $a_n$, we have to deal with the $a_{n-1}$ separately, so I left that as the first column, then indexed by $a_i$ to sum the columns.

$$\begin{array} { l l l l l l l l l ll l l } 
 \frac{ a_1}{11} & = & \frac{ a_0}{11} & & & & +  a_{-1}  \times \frac{ 10^1 - 1 }  { 9 \times 11} \\
\frac{ a_2}{11^2} & = & \frac{ a_1}{11^2}  & & & + a_0 \times \frac{ 10^1 - 1 } { 9 \times 11^2} & + a_{-1}  \times \frac{ 10^2 - 1 }  { 9 \times 11^2} \\
\frac{ a_3}{11^3} & = & \frac{ a_2}{11^3}  & & + a_1 \times \frac{ 10^1 - 1 } { 9 \times 11^3 } & + a_0 \times \frac{ 10^2 - 1 } { 9 \times 11^3} & + a_{-1}  \times \frac{ 10^3 - 1 }  { 9 \times 11^3} \\
\vdots & = & \vdots & \ldots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
\hline   
S & = & \frac{S}{11} + \frac{1}{11} & + \ldots & + \frac{ a_1}{11^2} \times \frac{11}{10} & + \frac{ a_0}{11^1} \times \frac{11}{10} & + \frac{ a_{-1}} { 11^0} \times \frac{ 11}{ 10} \\
& = & \frac{S}{11} + \frac{1}{11} &  & + \frac{S}{10} & + \frac{1}{10} & + \frac{11}{10} 
\end{array} $$
Hence, $ S = \frac{ 142}{ 89}$.
